# How to add an item in the next free spot

Tags: python, django

I have a program that lets a user add a customer, name, and an RD number (the RD number is similar to an ID) I have an import script that uploads already existing details to my database, but there are free slots where the RD numbers should be (meaning that some customers have high RD numbers, some have low, some have inbetween. They are not all filled in order.) I need to set my program so that when I add a customer, the next available RD number is set by default.

My Models

```
class Customer(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        description = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
        active = models.BooleanField()

        def __unicode__(self):
                return self.name

class Route_distinguisher(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
        comment = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
        active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
        rd = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='33763:264')

        def __unicode__(self):
                return self.name
```

So as an example, some of the fields are as follows.

Customer    Name      RD

trustco     trustco   33763:264100

namco       namco     33763:264101

There should be customers inserted here

cell        cellone   33763:264110

And here

namp        nampost   33763:264115

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure whether I got the question correctly, but if you want to get numbers from a pool, I would

1. define a function `next_available_rd()` or even a new model `class RD_handler(models.Model)` which includes such a function.
2. If you just want to increment the RD, you can store the `current_id` in your database using the `RD_handler` and implement your logic to get the next id in the method `next_available_rd()`. The samelogic applies if you dra IDs from a pool or have a more elaborate schema for ID generation.